# Is Narayan really quoting a traditional proverb, and from which Indian language/culture?

Tags: short-stories, cultural-context, r-k-narayan

In the story "Fellow-Feeling" from R. K. Narayan's short story collection [*Malgudi Days*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malgudi_Days_(short_story_collection)) (which I've been [reading online](https://eruditesdps.files.wordpress.com/2017/01/malgudi-days-narayan_-r-k_.pdf)), a proverb is mentioned in passing:

> Rajam Iyer leaned back in his seat, reminding himself of a proverb which said that if you threw a stone into a gutter it would only spurt filth in your face.

I'd never heard this before, but I like it. In context it's a metaphor for not arguing with idiots, along the same lines as *"don't mud-wrestle with a pig, because you'll both get filthy but the pig will enjoy it"* and *"don't play chess with pigeons: they'll knock over the pieces, crap all over the board, and then strut around like they've won"*. But I like this one even better, and I'd like to know its source. The story suggests it's a traditional or well-known proverb, but [Googling it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06inU.png) only gave me pages about this very story.

**Did Narayan invent this saying, or is it really a proverb? If the latter, what language/culture does it come from?**

It might be that my Google search for a real proverb failed because this only became known in *English* through Narayan, and in some Indian language/culture it might indeed be well known. For what it's worth, the character Rajam Iyer is a Brahmin, reading a book in Tamil, travelling from Madras to Bangalore. (I don't know enough about Indian cultures to know which of these facts is most likely to be relevant.)

Comment: RK Narayan is himself Tamil, and I'd judge "reading a book in Tamil, travelling from Madras" to be most relevant - the proverb if it exists, is almost certain to be a Tamil proverb, but I don't know Tamil well enough to Google likely versions of the proverb

Comment: Related (there is such a Tamil proverb, apparently): https://english.stackexchange.com/q/310811/256322

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The book *A Classified Collection of Tamil Proverbs* by the Rev. Herman Jensen, Danish Missionary, Madras (published in 1897 by The Methodist Episcopal Publishing House, Madras) lists the proverb on page 258:

> Proverb 2327: சேற்றிலே கல் விட்டு எறிந்தால், மேலே தெறிக்கும்.
>
> If you throw stones into mud it will splash over yourself.
>
> *"If you will stir up the mire, you must bear the smell."*
>   *"He who blows in the dust fills his eyes with it."*
>   *"Do not throw clods into dung to splatter your own clothes."*

A [transliteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_15919) of the proverb would read: *cēṟṟilē kal viṭṭu eṟintāl, mēlē teṟikkum.*

A scanned copy of the book can be accessed at the website of the [Rare Book Society of India (RBSI)](https://www.rarebooksocietyofindia.org/postDetail.php?id=196174216674_10150930350756675).

[image: Tamil Proverbs, Rev. Herman Jensen, page 258]

Answer (score 7):

It's a bit of an odd translation - but the actual proverb goes:

> சேற்றில கல்லெறிஞ்சா அது மூஞ்சிலே தெறிக்கும்
>   If you throw a stone at mud, it will splatter on your face.

Apparently it is Tamil, but not specifically unique to the Tamil-Brahmin culture, who have a few linguistic quirks of their own.

There's a less polite version that seems a better fit:

> பீ மேலே கல்லெறிஞ்சா உன் உதட்டுல தெறிக்கும்
>   If you throw stones at urine, it will land on your mouth.

While I'm unsure if a conservative/orthodox Brahmin would use such a term, I'm assured that linguistic standards of that generation were much less Puritan than ours.

Comment: Might be good to have the reading of the Tamil phrases rendered in the English alphabet (I'm guessing that it's something close to "chellil kallerinjal muukil therikkum" in Malayalam?)

Comment: I felt it would be too busy, and I've no idea how to transliterate a hard itrt. :D

Comment: For context - the first would be "Setril kallerithal athu munjiyil therikkum" the latter is "pee mela kallerinthal athu un uthathil therikkum". Yes, Pee is exactly the same in english and tamil

Comment: Isn't பீ usually #2, not #1? :P

Comment: uhm. Curse my excessively polite upbringing. I usually use somewhat more formal terms for this.